# automatic accepting of videocalls on Raspberry Pi 3B+?

Tags: video-conferencing, raspberry-pi

I look for a videocall-solution that exists both for Android and Raspberry Pi.
The coders of Jitsi write that it will not work on the Pi, what a bummer. So I looked more into Nextcloud Talk and Google Duo.

The main functions I need:

- running in fullscreen (well atleast if a call comes in) on the Pi's desktop
- automatic accepting calls (no buttonpress needed)
- nice to have: controlling the TV over CEC (like power off or something to either turn on and off or just skip from and back to the TV program. Eg. Google Chromecast works that way in the same TV.

Oh and the Pi has a Microsoft HD3000 (1280x720) cam with microsphone. What should I consider to put my time in? Google Duo? Nextcloud Talk? Or something completely different?

Comment: What does run on the Pi? Or would it be OK if you had to switch images? In the latter case, your question could be narrowed down to Android, as you can run that on the Pi as well?

Comment: well I probably could run Android, but I doubt it is useful without a touchscreen or any input-device? I feel like Raspbian can be do automated scripting better than Android?

Comment: Well – it's your choice, and you define the requirements for this question. I fully get your point (and agree: none of my Pis runs Android, all of them are Linux ones). Just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks :) Looks like a kinda niche project to use a Pi for. Though since Microsoft stopped Skype-support for TVs I see no other solution. Hm...

Should check if there is somehow a hacky way to use Google Duo perhaps.

Comment: Aw, there are also open-source solutions that don't require you using the services of a data kraken to listen in. E.g. Jitsi ;)

Comment: Tried it between PC and the Pi, on the Pi I couldn't get the microphone of the USB-cam working and after like 5mins the Pi crashed unrecoverable, had to pull the USB-cable. Perhaps a Chromium-bug, who knows. The biggest problem is, there must be a way to detect a incoming call to script a CEC-event to switch the TV from the internal tuner to the HDMI-port....

Comment: I guess I will stick to SIP and videocalls with Linphone, atleast both ecosystems (Android and Raspbian) have a working client. :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. You know you can [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)? Might be helpful to others (of course with a few more details than in your last comment ;)